# indice of vector element in loop - R

Tags: r

i have a numbers vector and i need to find the index of the first number that is greater than 24 and divisible by 13, if no number answers the conditions print 0. this is the code i wrote:

```
numbers_vector=c(1,5,26,7,94)
for(i in numbers_vector){
  if(i>24&&i%%13==0){
    print(i)
  }else{
    print(0)
  }
}
```

the answer it returns:

```
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 26
[1] 0
[1] 0
```

it should return the number 3 (the index), as 26 answers the conditions.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
which.max(numbers_vector>24 & numbers_vector%%13==0)
```

This will give you the result you're looking for, but if none of the numbers fits, it returns NA. If you want zero in such cases, do this :

```
a=which.max(numbers_vector>24 & numbers_vector%%13==0)
ifelse(is.na(a), 0, a)
```

Two general comments: a. avoid automatically going for the for loop. R's greatest strength is in vectorized calculations.
B. Avoid using print to return your result.

Comment: Or `which.max` and you can remove the `[1]`

Comment: Add four characters to remove three?

Comment: Good point. I had assumed `which.max` would be faster for not loading a larger vector then subsetting but I guess there's really no reason to think that it would make a significant difference relative to the actual operation.

Comment: Actually, yours is fractionally faster: `Unit: nanoseconds
 expr  min     lq    mean median     uq   max neval cld
   mx  938 1015.5 1448.83 1127.5 1311.5 26219   100   a
   rg 1178 1350.0 1569.39 1433.5 1604.5  9380   100   a`

Comment: thank you! we sort of have to use loops as the requirement in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Only a small change is needed:

```
numbers_vector=c(1,5,26,7,94)
for(i in numbers_vector){
  if(i>24 && i%%13==0){
    print(which(numbers_vector == i))
  }else{
    print(0)
  }

}
```

You are printing `i`, which is the number itself rather than its index

Comment: try `numbers_vector=c(1, 5, 26, 7, 94, 26)` and you'll see something strange.